# Cannot save field values from ListFieldIterator to list item

Tags: user-controls, rendering-template

I have the following issue. I created rendering template for list. This template is shown in New\Display\Edit forms. Then i've created two user controls: "mainCard" and "mainCard_Info". First control control contains save button and some additionsl markup. Second control contains ListFieldIterator. And second control is located inside first control.
When i open edit form ListFieldIterator shows all necessary fields and their current values. But when i change field values and try to save them into list item these changes do not apply to list item.

But if ListFieldIterator is located inside first control all changes save into list item.

Can anyone help me to realize case in which ListFieldIterator will be inside second control and i will can to save all changes to list item.

Thanks!